# How to open gzip text files in Gvim without unzipping?

Tags: gzip, vim, unzip

How to open Gzipped text files (*.gz) in Gvim without unzipping them first ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Solution mentioned in [VimDocs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#gzip-example) as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398771/1013072) by [therefromwhere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8331/therefromhere)

```
augroup gzip
 autocmd!
 autocmd BufReadPre,FileReadPre *.gz set bin
 autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost   *.gz '[,']!gunzip
 autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost   *.gz set nobin
 autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost   *.gz execute ":doautocmd BufReadPost " . expand("%:r")
 autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost *.gz !mv <afile> <afile>:r
 autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost *.gz !gzip <afile>:r
 autocmd FileAppendPre      *.gz !gunzip <afile>
 autocmd FileAppendPre      *.gz !mv <afile>:r <afile>
 autocmd FileAppendPost     *.gz !mv <afile> <afile>:r
 autocmd FileAppendPost     *.gz !gzip <afile>:r
augroup END
```

Comment: Do you add this to `.vimrc` or how do you use it?

Comment: Yes.Add this to `.vimrc`

Comment: I had `gzip` but no `gunzip` on my system so I replaced all instances of `gunzip` with `gzip -d` and this worked.  (And then I discovered that in a GNU environment, `gunzip` is just a script that forwards to `gzip -d`.)

Answer (score 7):

Vim should do this for you automatically.  At least it does for me.  There's also zless.  I'll see if I can find a resource that talks about how vim does this.

Comment: It does for me automatically in my home machine,but not in my office machine. Both have same Linux,same KDE,same Gvim (7.2) and same .gvimrc.

Answer (score 3):

There's a example in the vim docs how how to get this working: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#gzip-example

For what it's worth I didn't need to do this on Ubuntu 10.04 (vim v7.2), it worked out of the box.

Answer (score -11):

Opening them directly would just give you the raw binary compressed data. There's tools for everything, but they need to be used appropriately. Sledgehammers are not there to break eggs for breakfast, and text editors aren't there to unzip.

Comment: There are plenty of text editors that will transparently decompress for you, including Emacs, and according to [this thread](http://markmail.org/message/oyobjz4gqaqvta3w#query:+page:1+mid:fakbg4c56xynkudr+state:results), Gvim.