# How to open and edit a *.gz file within vim (with auto unzip/zip)

Tags: vim, gzip, archive

Is it possible to auto unzip/zip `*.gz` files within vim?

Comment: I generally pipe it to 'less'. zcat file.gz | less

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`zip/unzip` cannot open `*.gz` files as far as I know.

Vim can open `*.gz` files with the help of `gzip/gunzip` like [this](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#gzip-example)

Its already discussed here on SO

[How to open gzip text files in Gvim without unzipping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396363/how-to-open-gzipped-text-files-gz-in-gvim-without-unzipping-them-first)

Comment: It will depend on the system. For me `vim` did work, but not `vi`.

Answer (score 38):

My vim installation does this by default.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15) on OpenSUSE 12.1
```

Also, check this link: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=902668

Comment: Mine worked too. `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:32)`

Comment: It's builtin/default functionality but requires support from a gzip executable. On Microsoft Windows, this command will need to be installed separately. Once I did that (using Chocolatey), the default installation allowed gzip'd files to open in their decompressed format.

Answer (score 1):

I have searched for this answer as well, specifically for Fedora.

So on Fedora, you need to install the package `vim-enhanced`:

```
sudo dnf install vim-enhanced
```

Now it is possible to just edit gzipped files like this:

```
vim my.log.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, works for me - I am not sure if something extra needs to be installed on the server however:

zless filename.gz

Comment: zless or gzless is a viewer. OP presumably wants to edit the archived file

Answer (score 0):

`vim` will open `.gz` files when called from the command line. however, in executing `:h iskeyword`, `vim` attempts to open a tab and in this case it fails to read in the `.gz` associated with vim's options.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did

1. Unzip the .gz file   -->    `gunzip YourFile.gz`  (This unzips the file and puts in the same directory)
2. Then use vim to open it   -->   `vim YourFile`