# How to view zst file using Vim?

Tags: vim, zstd

I'm trying to view some log files in zst format. I can use `zstdcat` to view the content, but when I do `vim <filename.zst>`, there're only garbled text. Is there a similar way as `zstdcat` to view zst file with Vim as well?

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5463559/7976758 but with different commands — `zstdcat` instead of `gz`.

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#gzip-example Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+open+gzipped+file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use Zstandard to compress data so a `*.zst` file is not readable text and there is no point opening it directly in a *text* editor. You will have to decompress it first, which is what `zstdcat` does:

```
zstdcat is equivalent to zstd -dcf
```

and then open the decompressed text in Vim.

To view the content of a `*.zst` file in Vim, from your shell:

```
$ view <(zstdcat filename)
$ zstdcat filename | view -
```

To view the content of a `*.zst` file from Vim:

```
:enew | r !zstdcat filename
```

Note that, in both cases, you are not viewing the `*.zst` file itself but a copy of its decompressed content.

Of course, the whole thing could be streamlined and turned into a plugin similar to `:h zip`.

Answer (score 0):

With the [2016 commit](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/1232/files#diff-5f8d81643e72786ef88451ff842e1f0f677e4659e94d4684e82fca6634f2a277R23) this feature was added to Vim in the gzip plugin

To view a file today within the shell, use `vim file.zst`